# PHP Count search result from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script doing a search record from mysql database, how can i add a count for total query return from mysql? eg. i search "ABC", total search results are 3, i want to display this after the search "total search found: 3". Have been trying below code so far and not making any good progress, anyone can can assist? Thanks

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'stock');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

try
{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";charset=" . DB_CHARSET . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false]);
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    die($ex->getMessage());
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `Name` LIKE ? OR `shopfront_signage` LIKE ? ");

$stmt->execute(["%" . $_POST['search'] . "%", "%" . $_POST['search'] . "%"]);

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (isset($_POST['ajax']))
{
    echo json_encode($results);
}

//$resultscount= $results[0];
//echo $resultscount;
$query = mysqli_query($stmt);
$resultrow = mysqli_num_rows($query);
echo 'Total search found: ' . $resultrow;

?>
```

Comment: May be `count($results)`..

Comment: Do not catch the exceptions if you do not know what to do with them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$count = $stmt ->rowCount();
```

I'd put this directly under the execute.

Comment: [`rowCount`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount) is not guaranteed to work for `SELECT` statements

Comment: I've never had an issue in 7 plus years.

Comment: I got another question, how to number/index the table with query return after the search? eg. 3 records will list first column "No" from 1, 2 & 3.

Comment: @robin I don't usually use fetchAll, I use fetch. Fetch grabs one row at a time. I loop through all the rows while ($row=$stmt->fetch()) { process your rows }.... but there are many ways. You can search php.net for fetchAll and fetch styles,.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `count()`, e.g.

```
echo 'Total search found: ' . count($results);
```